# Text layout across different columns

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I wonder if there is some library I have missed that allows me to distribute text among different text objects and have it reflow depending on size, newspaper style? it's something pretty easily done in web but I can't find anything like it on Java for Android.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any Android Layouts that work that way. You could probably create one that mimics the way html and css work though.

another option is to make your content with the Web technologies that you are used to and just display it inside of a WebView in your application. That would likely be a lot easier than trying to create the Layout yourself.

Comment: Well, I tried appcelerator titanium but performance is our premise here so it's a no go, maybe I should ask for a way to determine how much text can I accommodate in a textfield depending on textfield's width and height versus font size or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I had two text fields of different size and different default justification plus offset from the screen border. I simply overlapped them in the same space. Depending on what needed to be displayed, I would null out one field and fill in the other. It kept me from creating 2 different layouts and having to get creative with the text formatting.

Comment: Well, my intention is to have several textfields and have text distribute among all of them, it's somehow like your example but a lot more complex.